# Video disappears when trying to fullscreen in react-native-video

Tags: android, react-native

When I'm on the page the video is visible and plays just like I want it. When I press on it I call the `presentFullscreenPlayer()` function and the video disappears while I can still hear it.

The video:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.video} onPress={() => this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()}>
  <View>
    <Video source={video}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
           ref={ref => this.player = ref} // Store reference
           rate={1.0}                     // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
           volume={1.0}                   // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
           muted={false}                  // Mutes the audio entirely.
           paused={true}                 // Pauses playback entirely.
           resizeMode="cover"             // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
           repeat={false}                  // Repeat forever.
           playInBackground={false}       // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
           playWhenInactive={false}       // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
           progressUpdateInterval={250.0} // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
           onLoadStart={this.loadStart}   // Callback when video starts to load
           onLoad={() => {
                      this.player.seek(10);
                      }}      // Callback when video loads
           onProgress={this.setTime}      // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
           onEnd={this.onEnd}             // Callback when playback finishes
           onError={this.videoError}      // Callback when video cannot be loaded
           style={styles.locatieVideo} />
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I think my styling might be wrong but I'm not about sure what to do with it.

Styling:

```
  locatieVideo:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 250,
    height: 200,
    zIndex: 501,
  },
  video:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 500,
  },
```

EDIT:

I also noticed it does get fullscreen but it stays behind the background image. The page is a modal created with react-native-router-flux. Can it have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the function `this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()` is not supported on Android.